# When are spaces with homeomorphic suspensions homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

**For what restrictions on topological spaces $A$ and $B$ does the following
implication hold?**

$$\Sigma A \cong \Sigma B \implies A\cong B$$

where $\Sigma$ is the unreduced suspension.

This should be equivalent (by simply removing the suspension points) to asking when:

$$A\times \mathbb{R} \cong B\times \mathbb{R} \implies A\cong B$$

and is thus related to [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26385/when-factors-may-be-cancelled-in-homeomorphic-products), [3](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64029/if-a-manifold-suspends-to-a-sphere/64036#64036) and [4](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/125935/cancellation-law-for-mn-times-mathbb-r-nn-times-mathbb-r). (Unfortunately I don't understand the
counterexample by Sergei Ivanov in [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26385/when-factors-may-be-cancelled-in-homeomorphic-products))

In [3](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64029/if-a-manifold-suspends-to-a-sphere/64036#64036) Igor Belegradek says:

```
I guess, I just like to advertize that fact that if two closed manifolds
become homeomorphic after multiplying by RR , then they are h-cobordant. :)
```

Thus, together with the h-cobordism theorem[6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-cobordism#Precise_statement_of_the_h-cobordism_theorem), **it follows that for closed simply connected manifolds the implication holds**.

This is all completely new to me, is it right?